# MySQL : 6.6.5.0 version of MySql.Data couldn't load

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, mysql.data

I use Entity FrameWork 5.0 and MySql connector 6.7.4 . I have a simple MVC Razor 4 application. When I start my appliaction there is an error like this :

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried that unload and load my MySqlData dll from NuGet but it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `EF5` a corollary is that you have to use version `4.5` of the framwework. This then requires that you use version `6.7.4.0` of the MySql connector libraries as you've stated, yet your error implies that you are using version `6.6.5.0` for .Net 4.0.

You need to remove the current version you have and download the correct version from NuGet. Alternatively, you can download directly from the [MySql Dev site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net)

Also, make sure that you reference `MySql.Data`, `MySql.Data.Entity` and `MySql.Web` in your application, and that they are all version `6.7.4.0`.

You may also need to update the `<system.data>` section of your `web.config`. Try this:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: I use 6.7.4.0 version of all of them. I checked again but they are in true version. Where is my mistake?

Comment: In that case you possibly need to manually update your web.config. See my updated answer.